# Is object property functional?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owl-api

I am using the OWL-API 5 to load all the object property axioms in my ontology as follows:

```
File ontology = new File("examples/ontology.owl");
File individual = new File("examples/individuals.owl");
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();

IRI documentIRI = IRI.create(ontology);
IRI ontologyIRI = IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test");

SimpleIRIMapper mapper = new SimpleIRIMapper(ontologyIRI, documentIRI);
manager.getIRIMappers().add(mapper);

OWLOntology kb = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(individual);

Stream<OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom> objectPropertyAxioms = kb.axioms(AxiomType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_ASSERTION);
objectPropertyAxioms.forEach(axiom -> {
    System.out.println("Found object property axiom " + axiom);

    OWLIndividual object = axiom.getObject();
    OWLIndividual subject = axiom.getSubject();
    OWLObjectPropertyExpression property = axiom.getProperty();
});
```

Returns:

```
Found object property axiom ObjectPropertyAssertion(<http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#Q> <http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#x> <http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#y>)
```

Now, I'd like to determine if the property is functional. This is what I tried so far:

```
if (EntitySearcher.isFunctional(property, kb)) {
    LOGGER.debug("Property " + property + " is declared as functional");
} else {
    LOGGER.debug("Property " + property + " is NOT declared as functional");
}
```

Returns:

```
Property <http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#Q> is NOT declared as functional
```

I think that `EntitySearcher.isFunctional(p,o)` is looking for [functional object property axioms](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Functional_Object_Properties) that make the specified object property functional, which doesn't seems to exist in my ontology (i.e., `ontology.axioms(AxiomType.FUNCTIONAL_OBJECT_PROPERTY)` returns nothing).

---

This is what I have in my ontology:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#" xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test"/>

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#Q">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
</rdf:RDF>
```

And individuals:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
        <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test"/>
    </owl:Ontology>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#x">
        <Q rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#y"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#y"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

*(Both files were created using Prótegé 5.5.0)*. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: why do you assume that the property is functional? There is no such axiom in your ontology nor can it be inferred by a standard OWL reasoner which does use deductive reasoning. If you're talking about your instance data where there is only one such property assertion for individual `x`, then you have to read about Open World Assumption in OWL and even that won't change anything, the inference you want is only achievable by inductive reasoning, i.e. from the specific to something general. Just my two cents ...

Comment: to be clear, I'm _not_ trying to infer anything at all, I just wan't to read the file and "extract" the functional object property axiom

Comment: but then the method you're calling would work on the given sample data ... as long as the Java variable `property` specifies the correct object property with the correct URI `http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#Q` - also ,are you sure you loaded the correct ontology?

Comment: yes, I did load the correct ontology (checked twice haha), and I have updated the first message to be more explicit about how I import my ontology (maybe it has something to do with my problem?)

Comment: you never mentioned ontology imports ... use `isFunctional` with a second argument being the imports closure of your ontology

Answer (score 1):

To answer the implicit question about `EntitySearcher::isFunctional`, yes, it checks if there are functional property axioms for the property received in input.

I believe your ontology has enough information for that.

To provide a complete example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test#" xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test" xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:test="http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/2020/0/test"/>
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test#Q">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#FunctionalProperty"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test#x">
        <test:Q rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test#y"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/owlapi/test#y"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

With this ontology, EntitySearcher returns true when checking for functional properties.

Edit: in your updated question, you're using `kb.axioms(AxiomType)`, you need to tell it to include imports.

Comment: Tried your example -- it worked flawlessly! But it doesn't seems to work in my case, when the ontology is stored as separe files (ABox and TBox). I have updated the first message to provide the full code.